# How to mute an iframe content?

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, vimeo, mute

I have a **3rd party iframe** containing videos from youtube, vimeo ,...

Is there a generic way to mute the iframe content **independently** from the video/audio **source**?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25354184/how-to-mute-an-iframe, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654655/a-way-to-mute-an-iframe-using-jquery-or-css

Comment: As of 2021, this is not currently possible. If you want it to be supported, staring [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=985312) may help Chromium contributors gauge interest. If you have a specific use case, you can also leave a comment on that issue (but please don't comment simple/unhelpful things like "I need this!" - just star it instead)

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1.** First you need to access the iframe.

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeId');
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
```

**Step2.** Once you get the inner document reference, you can access its inside DOM elements. Suppose your video/audio element id is `mediaElem` then.

```
var MediaSource = innerDoc.getElementById('mediaElem');
```

**Step3.** Now you could do whatever you want with it. In your case if you want to mute, simply set.

```
MediaSource.muted=true;
```

Comment: That will fail at step 1 because it is a 3rd party iframe.

Comment: Then you can't access it. It's a `cross-origin policy` but if you've everything on the same domain, it works like a charm.

Comment: its a 3rd party iframe. i can not be accessible

Comment: TypeError: Cannot set property 'muted' of null

Comment: @naturevetri Which iframe are you referring to? Be ensure you've used the correct Iframe Id and it should be within the same domain

Comment: i am using cross domain

Comment: Then it won't be possible, sorry. You can control iframes which are on your domain only.

Comment: i can access the cross domain iframe

Answer (score 0):

You can also, call it and set it's volume to zero or pause it, in javsscript it is something like this: `var media = document.getElementById('mediaId');
media.volume = 0; /*set volume to zero|takes values btw 0-1*/
media.pause(); /*pause the audio/video*/`