# How to mute a iframe audio

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Is it possible to mute an iframe audio

i have tried like following

```html
 <iframe id="Iframe" src="#someurl"></iframe>
```

```js
 var iframe = document.getElementById('Iframe');
 var MediaSource = innerDoc.getElementById('mediaElem')
 MediaSource.muted=true;
```

Comment: this link may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33528890/how-to-mute-an-iframe-content

Comment: If the iframe document isn't cross-domain, change `innerDoc`to `contentDocument`.

Comment: i have tried this, but not working

Comment: i am using cross domain

Comment: Then you can't mute an audio on the third-party's page.

Comment: Check which element returned from innerDoc.getElementById('mediaElem'). "MediaSource" is not good name to variable... change it to "mediaSource"

Comment: ok, i shall change
is it any problem with variable name??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mute an iframe content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33528890/how-to-mute-an-iframe-content)

Comment: i have tried this, but not working