# How to mute the sound of a webpage when viewing through iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=4xVYV-iRE4SEoAPS2YHgAQ"></iframe> 

    <iframe src="https://www.example.com/"></iframe> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

In the above code example.com site plays some sound I want to mute that sound. I want to mute the sound only for that site/iframe

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/25354184/6320435

Comment: @keziah but there is no working solution, that solution is for audio and video elements and am also refering this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement.

Comment: what if you put the video url onto the `<video>`?

Comment: @keziah No, I want to do this way

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, browsers don't allow you to interact with the with the DOM of the iframe embedded elements. It's possible that your whole page could be muted, and I'll try to fiddle up that solution, however, since that's not what you need, I guess you're just out of luck. @keziah suggested putting video URL in `<video>` tags and I am not aware of a better course of action.